# remove needs a query at src/mongo/shell/collection.js

Tags: mongodb

Getting this error when I run db.messages.remove(). "remove needs a query at src/mongo/shell/collection.js". any suggestions to resolve this error?

Comment: Note: if you actually want to remove *all* documents in a collection it is faster to a do a [`collection.drop()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/). The `remove()` operation will delete documents individually & update indexes as the documents are deleted; a `drop()` will immediately delete all documents & indexes for the collection.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As the message says you need to provide a query, but it can be an empty one (if you want to remove all documents):

```
db.messages.remove({})
```

**EDIT:** I would like emphasize the comment made by [Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104095/remove-needs-a-query-at-src-mongo-shell-collection-js/25104106#comment39079723_25104095):

> Note: if you actually want to remove *all* documents in a collection it is faster to a do a [`collection.drop()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/). The `remove()` operation will delete documents individually & update indexes as the documents are deleted; a `drop()` will immediately delete all documents & indexes for the collection.

Comment: i wonder why they don't just mark no parameter as valid instead of giving a message. does ```{}``` really mean anything?

Comment: @MurWade in MongoDB Linux it is as you say. Not in Windows where the argument has to be provided. Really dont' know why

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to drop the collection `messages`, then you need to execute `db.messages.drop()`.

Otherwise, the command `db.messages.remove()` is used to delete a particular document and therefore you need to write a query to allow MongoDB engine to know which document needs to be gotten rid of. For ex. db.messages.remove({_id : }).

The lack of {_id : } is causing the error that `remove needs a query...`.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

`db.collectionname.remove({});`

result :

```
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 7 })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all collections from MongoDB database, use below Syntax:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(
function(collection_name){
    print('CollectionName: '+ collection_name +', '+ db[collection_name].remove({})
)
```

});

**Output:**

```
CollectionName: Document_CODE, WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 20 })
CollectionName: Document_DATA, WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 10 })
CollectionName: Document_NAME, WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 10 })
CollectionName: Document_COLLE, WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
```